# List of environments

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm looking for a way to have a different list for a few environments I have defined. I saw a post related to that but I lost it (maybe the person who asked deleted the question) hence why I'm asking for help to do that.

These are the environments:

```
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=L]{Hipótesis}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{Postulado}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=S]{Teorema}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{Principio}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{Ley}
```

Also, right now I have used the `\listoftheorems` command but it mixes them all and the name of the list is in English (I want it in Spanish).

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

The title of the lists should be:

> Lista de Postulados
>
> Lista de Leyes
>
> Lista de Principios
>
> Lista de Hipótesis
>
> Lista de Teoremas

Also, I do not want to have an empty page between the lists if it's possible please.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 20pt]{book}
% fuente de letra:
\usepackage{tgcursor}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
% matemáticas:
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
% idioma:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % 'cuadro' es el título del caption de table por defecto siguiendo indicaciones de RAE; es-tabla lo cambia a 'tabla'
% gestión de párrafos (hace innecesario indicar el salto de línea con doble barra y elimina el indent de todos los párrafos):
\usepackage{parskip}
% enlaces a URLs:
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
% gráficos:
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, caption, subcaption}
% tablas:
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=L]{Hipótesis}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{Postulado}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=S]{Teorema}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{Principio}
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{Ley}
\begin{document}
\begin{Postulado}[Cuarto postulado]
Hi
\end{Postulado}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question please? It would be helpful and means that people do not need to create your document (which may be subtly different to yours).

Comment: I think that is everything you need, if you need more let me know. All the enviroments works like that one